# Delete duplicate records when joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join 2 tables and check if there are any duplicate records.
If there are any I need to delete the duplicate records from dbo table

stage table

```
market cost ra file_id 
CA     32   2   200
CA     44   5   200
TX     22   2   200
```

dbo table

```
market cost ra  file_id
CA     72   9    100
CA     44   5    100
TX     22   2    100
```

When I join stage and dbo table, I want to delete the duplicate records

Output I want to see is:

dbo table

```
market cost ra  file_id
CA     72   9    100
```

I tried query:

```
    select s.market, s.cost,s.ra , s.[file_id] ,count(*)
    from stage table s
    join dbo table d on s.market=d.market and  s.cost=d.cost, s.ra=d.ra
    group by  s.market, s.cost,s.ra , s.[file_id]    
    having count(*) > 1;
```

Once I delete the duplicate records I will ingest the staged data to dbo.

Can anyone help me with delete statement.

Comment: i tried the select query and had success and getting the2 records in my output but not sure writing the delete statement.
What ever query i tried is in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use `EXISTS`

> ```
> DELETE 
> FROM dbo_table
> WHERE  EXISTS (
>     select 1
>     from stage_table s
>     WHERE s.market = dbo_table.market AND  dbo_table.cost = s.cost AND  s.ra=dbo_table.ra)
>     
>     ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo_table
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> market | cost | ra | file_id
> :----- | ---: | -: | ------:
> CA     |   72 |  9 |     100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d2bdd7cf32961236f54aebb99db90df)*

Answer (score 0):

I try to guess the requirement a bit since in my eyes you are not being very clear. You try to describe your way of implementing a solution.
It would  be better to state first and in short what you want to achieve.

You also do not define clearly what you mean by duplicate record. I guess when the columns `market`, `cost` and `ra` have equal values (no matter the other column(s), then you consider it a duplicate.

My guess is:

- You want to insert data from `staging` into `dbo`
- The problem is some rows are duplicate, which you would like to overwrite during the process or delete before inserting them

You can delete them before you do the insertion.

```
delete from dbo d where exists (select 'X' from staging s where s.market = d.market and s.cost = d.cost and s.ra = d.ra)
```

Then you do the insertion.

```
insert into dbo select market, cost, ra, file_id from staging
```

I trust you can understand the SQL statements, so I won't explain them here. Feel free to comment otherwise.